# Android to .Net asmx web service communication

Tags: android, web-services

I need to use an webservice (.Net asmx) where are few methods accepting .Net objects as parameters. One method, for example, has this signature:

```
public Item SaveData(string itemName, string guid, Location storeAddress, Price price)
```

The first 2 parameters are simple objects (strings) so nothing special to send to the WS. My issue is with the last 2 parameters. The location is defined on .Net as:

```
public class Location
{
    double longitude, latitude;

    public Location()
    {
    }

    public Location(double longitude, double latitude)
    {
        this.Longitude = longitude;
        this.Latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Location(String longitude, String latitude)
    {

        this.Longitude = double.Parse(longitude);
        this.Latitude = double.Parse(latitude);
    }

    public double Longitude
    {
        get { return longitude; }
        set { longitude = value; }
    }

    public double Latitude
    {
        get { return latitude; }
        set { latitude = value; }
    }
}
```

and the price something like //not all the code

```
public class Price {
    //private vars

    public Price(float price, float discount, string currency){
        //vars assignment 
    }

//more methods and properties
}
```

Now on Java (android), I'm using HttpClient with HttpParams to send post data.

My questions are: 
1. how do I build the JSON to send the required parameters to the server? 
2. is any tool to help me to build the request? I'm looking for something that knows to read the wsdl and to build a sample request.

Thank you.

Comment: you need [storm](http://storm.codeplex.com/) to inspect your wsdl

Comment: Storm doesn't help me. It doesn't know to build JSON request. I don't need XML.

Comment: if you analyze the xml, it will be explanatory enough to build the json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build **json** string by analyzing the input *XML* for your web-method. For that I would recommend you to use free tools like [STORM](http://storm.codeplex.com/) (or feature-rich paid tools like [WCF Storm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx)) that translates your web-service's *WSDL*. Other than that, you may use [jsoneditoronline.org](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) and [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to build and inspect the json string.

As an example, following is the structure for your json string that you need to pass to the web-method.

```
{
    "itemName": "bla bla bla",
    "guid": "32sd4fgsd654fg53dfsg",
    "storeAddress": {
        "longitude": 12.02,
        "latitude": 10.32
    },
    "price": {
        "price": 100.01,
        "discount": 5.1,
        "currency": "USD"
    }
}
```

**You need to replace the dummy values with the real ones.*

Last but not least, you may use some chrome-browser plugins like **Postman - REST Client** to send the json string to your webservice and test the responses.